# pass LocalTime to PreparedStatement

Tags: java, time, timestamp, prepared-statement

I want to pass a java localtime to a PreparedStatement (java.sql.) like this:

```
ps.setTimestamp(id++, (localtime));
```

I do not know if  `setTimestamp`  is the right one or if I should use `setTime` or even another one. I did not find one which fits localtime directly so how can I convert it so that I can pass it to a Preparedstatement?

Comment: Depends on what data type the column in the database has... Which one is it? A timestamp is either a datetime (date and time) or a representation as an instant in milliseconds. There may be more possibilities.

Comment: You could convert all your time data to the epoch time and pass that into the prepared statement as long

Comment: In the database it is actually a datetime but it caused some problems to pass a datetime since I need only time so that's why I want to pass time only

Comment: @MadScientist but a `datetime` is not a `time`.

Comment: so I can't pass a time in the code to datetime in the database?

Comment: @MadScientist it doesn't make sense to have a `datetime` column, if you don't intend to use the date part.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't use it here but I think others use it at our project

Comment: @MadScientist then talk to those others. You can't just hijack a column and decide to use it as a different type. If the column is `datetime`, then you must use it as a `datetime`. It sounds like you're trying to do something wrong, so ask your colleagues before you break something.

Comment: @Kayaman good point, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.time` classes in `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` with the `set/getObject` methods since there are (currently) no specific methods for those types. The database driver needs to be recent enough to support those as well.

```
ps.setObject(1, localtime);
LocalTime loco = rs.getObject(1, LocalTime.class);
```

The column type needs to be correct too of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is the method `setTime(Time x)` in `PreparedStatement` and you can convert a `LocalTime` to a `java.sql.Time`:

```
LocalTime localTime = localTime.now();
preparedStatement.setTime(1, Time.valueOf(localTime);
```

**EDIT**
If your data type in the database is `DateTime`, then you have to pass a full timestamp, a `java.sql.Timestamp` which includes information about the date, too, not only the time.

If you want to use `java.time`, then you can use `LocalDateTime` instead of just `LocalTime` and convert that to a timestamp (and the other way round):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(now));
```

If you have a data type of `DATETIME` in the database column and you want to set the time as `LocalTime`, use `LocalDate.now()` in order to create a `LocalDateTime` instance having your `LocalTime` and then add it as query parameter:

```
// use your instance of LocalTime (now() is just an example)
LocalTime timeNow = LocalTime.now();
// get the date of today (or maybe another specific one)
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
// combine them
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.of(today, timeNow);
// add the converted combination as parameter
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(1, Timestamp.valueOf(now));
```

Comment: Assuming that the questioner is using a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, there is no reason to use the poorly designed and long outdated `Timestamp` class. `preparedStatement.setObject(1, now);` (where `now` is your `LocalDateTime` object).

Comment: @OleV.V I know, but that was already answered when I added this as an alternative.